# How to reload stunnel configuration file without restarting it on windows

Tags: windows, reload, stunnel

Is there a command line method(or any other approach) for instructing stunnel to reload its configuration file when running as a Windows standalone application?

When I started stunnel 4.56, I've recognized matching option in application's menu(Configuration->Reload stunnel.conf), but I was googling it without any success to find out how to do it not through stunnel's GUI.